# Consultar fecha de tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Cordial saludo.
Podrian ayudarme a saber como consultar la fecha en la que se creó una tabla en SQL server?

Así sea en query o via interfaz del mismo SQL server

Se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar la vista de sistema [`sys.tables`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT 
    name Tabla,
    create_date FechaCreacion
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name = 'TuTabla'
;
```